# Making a subnav menu appear on hover on main nav list items

Tags: html, css, hover

There's probably a very simple answer to this, and I'm most likely just at a level in my html/css where I still can't figure it out, but would somebody more knowledgeable be so kind as to give me a general idea how the hover effect of the subnav menu appearing on mouseover on the main nav items was made to work in the ff website?

http://www.bearena.com.au/

I've looked in the css file of that site and I can't find a :hover declaration for it.

Thanks!

Edit: I used Inspect element in Chrome to analyze this further and I've noticed that a new class name is added to the list item on hover and I'm guessing that is how the submenu gets displayed. How do I replicate this method? Is it in the CSS or is javascript involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would set up your sub levels to default to display:none; then on hover have it change to display: block; using a structure like this:

```
.main-nav ul.main-2-nav{
   display:none;
   height:YourMenuHeight;
   width:YourMenuWidth;
   position:relative;
   top:TopVariance;
   left:LeftVariance
}
.main-nav:hover > ul.main-2-nav{
    display:block;
}
```

I put in the position, top, and left attributes because they are normally used in these types of menu structures. If you wanted to add a third level to your menu, you would repeat this pattern making the necessary class name adjustments.

Comment: thanks, I've seen it done that way, but would you know how it was done in that particular site? I couldn't find anything in the site's CSS  that was similar to your example, so I thought there might be some other way...or maybe I wasn't looking in the right CSS file?

Comment: The method that is used in that particular site was being controlled through a combination of CSS and jQuery. The method that I was showing you is pure CSS

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was thinking and you just confirmed it for me. I'm not too familiar with jQuery so I might just have to do my nav the CSS way, like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.menu li:hover ul { display: block; }`

Comment: thanks, I'm interested to know how it was done in that particular site -- not really looking for another way to do it, just trying to break down how that particular hover effect was created in that site specifically as I can't seem to find the exact ":hover" declaration for it in the CSS file, so I was thinking maybe it was done differently.

Comment: To get the slide that was on there would require some javascript. But for the most part, the hover piece that we added is all you'd need to display the submenus.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, and I'm not too familiar with javascript so I guess I'll settle for the CSS way.